# C++11 Strange notation [0:size())

Tags: c++11, range, iunknown

Am I to understand from

> Stroutrup C++ Programming Language - Invariants

that the notation above is a range initializer or is this interpretive instruction to convey mathematically that the Vector class array range is between 0 and some predetermined size?

Should I even be using this book because it contains errors such as accessing a struct member from a variable of that struct using `.` instead of `->`?

Comment: The "error" is not an error, you're wrong....

Comment: I think what you're looking at is a [half-closed interval](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Half-ClosedInterval.html).

Comment: @Rakete1111 Can you please demonstrate accessing a struct member through a pointer to struct?

Comment: @FredLarson Is that legal syntax in C++ or is the author illustrating a point using  half-closed interval?

Comment: It's not legal C++ syntax, but you haven't given any context that indicates it was a code example.

Comment: @FredLarson If you have the book I mentioned or access to it it's on page 56 first paragraph.  I was simply wondering if the author was utilizing some neat syntax trick.

Comment: @Mushy You are asking something else, but [demo for both](https://godbolt.org/g/hJnatS).

Comment: @Rakete1111 I got it; He's accessing the struct from argument

Comment: BTW, note that this book is included in the [Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). Bjarne Stroustrup created C++ and is one of the foremost authorities on the language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a [half-closed interval](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Half-ClosedInterval.html). He's saying the index to a vector must be in the range of 0 up to but not including the vector's size. So `0` would be a valid index (assuming the vector is not empty), but `size()` would not. This is not a code example.